# Add rectangle shape to vector layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes

Let's say I have a document with a vector layer.

If I want to add a path to that layer with the Pen Tool, I select the Pen Tool in Path mode with Combine Shapes as Path Operation and draw the new path I want:

[image: pen tool ok]

If I do the same with the Rectangle Tool, Ellipse Tool, or any of the predefined shapes tool, I only get the path (no fill, no stroke):

[image: rectangle tool not ok]

In addition the two path seem "linked" to each other, like grouped together (they select together with the Path Selection Tool).

The only workaround I found is to select the rectangle, cut (Ctrl-X) it, change the tool to something else than Path Selection Tool, take back the Path Selection Tool, and paste the shape:

[image]

Is this inconsistency in behavior normal? How can I get the Rectangle Tool (or any other) work like the Pen Tool? In other words how can I simply draw multiple vector rectangles on an existing vector layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make sure the **Shape Selection Tool** is active and the object vector frame is visible (selected or not)
- Use the "*Rectangle Tool, Ellipse Tool, or any of the predefined shapes tool*" in the *Shape Mode* and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when
  starting to draw

  - Release it while drawing to make a rectangle, if not
    <kbd>Shift</kbd> will constraint the proportions making a square.

[image]